# JSF: difference between ViewActions and preRender event

Tags: java, jsf, view, seam

I'm not working with seam but i hear about seam's view actions. Can't we do that already with prerender event? executing logic and using the navigation handler to redirect?
Are view actions just an easier, built-in approach or do they have any extra benefit that prerender event listener doesn't have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Seam Faces documentation on this question providing a detailed in-depth comparison between both:

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/components.html#d0e433

Answer (score 0):

as you said page(view) actions are built-in easy approach, and abilitiy to define such actions in xml files keep your code really very clean and also they become more usefull with page params (another useful seam feature).